# Regex: How to grab wmsAuthSign for stream file (m3u8)?

Tags: php, regex

I am currently working with a PHP Regex code that grab token wmsAuthSign=* for a particular site, every token valid 30min.

```
<?php
$streamSite = "https://www.liveonlinetv247.info/embed/cartoonnetwork.php";
function writeFile($url, $channel) {
$File = $channel.".strm";
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
fwrite($Handle, $url);
fclose($Handle);
}
$input = @file_get_contents($streamSite) or die("Please try again later: $url");
preg_match("/(http.*?wmsAuthSign\=[^\&\">]+)/", $input, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Works great, but now i wants to know how to create Regex for direct URL: (Without PHP Web Site)

```
https://freeeucache2.streamlive.to/live/2tag4dzgwof5ma2/chunks.m3u8?nimblesessionid=6976110&wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTIvMTkvMjAxNyA3OjM1OjI5IEFNJmhhc2hfdmFsdWU9QlJDV1lCTzRKbnVaWEIvZDhmNURndz09JnZhbGlkbWludXRlcz0zMCZzdHJtX2xlbj0yMA==
```

I attached the last token wmsAuthSign=*.

Base64 Decode:

```
server_time=12/19/2017 7:35:29 AM&hash_value=BRCWYBO4JnuZXB/d8f5Dgw==&validminutes=30&strm_len=20
```

What options do I have to create Regex for this URL?

Comment: *"What options do I have to create Regex for this URL?"* Try and write a regex by yourself **first**, before asking here?

Comment: @chade_ I ask here that people like you might help? Or you're the kind of people who just want to raise the number of responses. And I try, while I write. But it's always good to get help while trying

Comment: your current regex doesn't work on it?

Comment: @revo Nope, because now I'm trying on direct stream url not PHP page. I'm trying to figure out what to change in the code

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @revo the wmsAuthSign part is token, and after 30min i need to open the url again to get a new token, What I need is to know how to grab / create new token as in my example above. I'm still trying but I'd love to get help

Answer (score 0):

This will get the token in Group 1:

```
wmsAuthSign=([^&?]+)$
```